# Windows - cp file in Git Bash

Tags: windows, git

I want to copy `/c/xampp/docs/fproject/.git` to `/c/xampp/docs/finalproject`.

I tried this command 
`cp /c/xampp/docs/fproject/.git finalproject`, 
and this message `cp:omitting directory 'c/xampp/docs/fproject/.git'` is shown but the file wasn't copied.

How can I copy `.git` file?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/35779/what-does-cp-omitting-directory-mean

Comment: Well it doesn't help for a beginner like me. :( @edi9999

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.git` is a directory, use `cp -r /c/xampp/docs/fproject/.git /c/xampp/docs/finalproject`

Comment: Your answer saved my day! Thanks Joran. :)